# How can I add jQuery to my web page using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My AngularJS SPA web page performs WebAPI calls to a server. When a user goes to a report page then I need to load jQuery so that it can be used. Very few users need the report page so I do not want to load jQuery at the start.

Can someone tell me a simple way to do the loading without needing to add in anything too complicated such as require.js or a complicated loader script. All I need is a very simple way to load in jQuery that will return a promise after the jQuery is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could so something like this:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = '/path/to/jQuery';
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

But there may be issues loading jQuery after Angular.

Answer (score 0):

You can load a script like this in javascript :

```
var jqueryScript=document.createElement('script');
jqueryScript.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
jqueryScript.setAttribute("src", jquerySrc);
```

Just put this code in a promise if you want to have something executed after load.

See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q